# Add xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" to the root element

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform XML into another xml with changes in namespace. I need to add namespace t the root element.
Input XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZMM_Data>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <DIRECT>3</DIRECT>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <Z1ZMM_B SEGMENT="1">
            <BOOKNO>2000456</BOOKNO>
        </Z1ZMM_B>
    </IDOC>
</ZMM_Data>
```

I need Expected output XML as below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ZMM_Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <DIRECT>3</DIRECT>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <Z1ZMM_B SEGMENT="1">
            <BOOKNO>2000456</BOOKNO>
        </Z1ZMM_B>
    </IDOC>
</ZMM_Data>
```

I Tried below XSLT but not getting the desired result:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">

<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:copy-of select="./*" />

</xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but getting out as:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZMM_Data xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <IDOC xmlns="" BEGIN="1">
        <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <DIRECT>3</DIRECT>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <Z1ZMM_B SEGMENT="1">
            <BOOKNO>2000456</BOOKNO>
        </Z1ZMM_B>
    </IDOC>
</ZMM_Data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you cannot do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/ZMM_Data">
    <ZMM_Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
    </ZMM_Data>
</xsl:template>
```

This will add a (redundant) namespace declaration to the root element. What you are doing is put the root element in a namespace.

Comment: Hi Michael,I am getting below error:-

net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 33; The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:template" is not bound

Comment: You can see it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rWF

Comment: ok I will try directly in to the process
I need to have 1st line as:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
but currently getting:-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>